# How to exit from doFn lyfecycle in apacheBeam,when a condition meets?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am going through lyfecycle management of Apache Beam DoFn.
I know,how to write Dofn using lifecycle methods.
But, I want to know,whether we can stop processing elements,if a certain condition meets.

Below,in code, In class I have a temp list,in which I have 1 as element.
When ,Bundle starts,I am checking,if 1 exists in temp,which is true,then I am calling finishBundle method.
What I was expecting that,when calling finish bundle,it will stop processing the elements.
But,it executes finishBundle method,and again start processing elemens.

```
  def __init__(self):
    self.temp=[1]

  def process(self, element):
    print("Processing element: %s" % element)
    yield element.upper()

  def start_bundle(self):
    if 1 in  self.temp :
      print("1 in bundle")
      self.finish_bundle()
    else:
      print("Bundle started")

  def finish_bundle(self):
    print("Bundle finished")

  def setup(self):
    dt_string = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    print("Worker started %s" % dt_string)

  def teardown(self):
    dt_string = datetime.now().strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")    
    print("Worker finished %s" % dt_string)
```

Here is my output:

```
changed = sane | beam.ParDo(ChangeWordDoFn()) \
              | beam.Map(print)

ib.show(changed)
```

Worker started 27/08/2022 09:05:09

1 in bundle

Bundle finished

Processing element: en

EN

Processing element: un

UN

.
.
.

Comment: When you say "we can stop processing element", you mean about not process the element or catching element ?

Comment: Stop processing--breaking out

Comment: I'm not sure if I got your point, but if you seek to stop the entire ParDo function from processing when I finding 1 for example, I'm not sure if that can be done. Because imagine your DoFn is parallelized through a DoFn transformation. Multiple workers are processing your pcollection. If 1 found in worker N, how other workers would be notified? I'm not sure if there is a way to notify all other workers to stop processing.

Comment: I don’t really understand your need. You can filter elements if needed or do a multi sink (tuple tags) on a certain condition (works also with errors).

Answer (score 0):

Methods such as `finish_bundle` are callbacks that are invoked when the bundle finishes, not triggers to invoke finishing of the bundle.

What you can do instead is record information on the DoFn instance to make subsequent process calls no-ops, e.g.

```
class MyDoFn(beam.DoFn):
  def __init__(self):
    self.temp=[1]

  def process(self, element):
    if not self.done:
        print("Processing element: %s" % element)
        yield element.upper()
        if [bundle-finishing-condition]:
            self.done = True

  def start_bundle(self):
    self.done = False
    print("Bundle started")

  def finish_bundle(self):
    print("Bundle finished")
```